# How to pass different types of activities

Tags: android, kotlin

I have class `Activity1` extends `AppCompatActivity` and class `Activity2` extends `AppCompatActivity`. I would like to call same method in both activities:

```
method(Activity1.this)   - parameter (Activity1 activity)

method(Activity2.this)   - parameter (Activity2 activity)
```

Of course something like this doesnt work, is it possible to use `Bundle` or something else? I just want to have general methods where I can pass different activities and later on call their methods.

Comment: Create a base activity class (lets call it BaseActivity) which will have the common method and then make Activity1 and Activity2 extend BaseActivity.

Comment: you can use Kotlin extension functions. i.e. define additional functionality without creating subclasses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a great idea to attempt to pass the Activity object reference.

- If the method is suppose to be Activity specific then you can simply create a BaseActivity (which extends `AppCompatActivity`)  and make `Activity1` & `Activity2` extend `BaseActivity`

**BaseActivity.java**

```
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   ...
   fun commonMethod(){
       ...
   }
}
```

**Activity1.java**

```
class Activity1 : BaseActivity() {
   ...
   //use commonMethod() where ever needed.
}
```

**Activity2.java**

```
class Activity2 : BaseActivity()  {
   ...
   //use commonMethod() where ever needed.
}
```

- If the target method is an utility method then you should create a separate Utility class and make that method as static method. If needed, you can pass `Context` Obj as method parameter.

Comment: I think I did not describe my needs correctly. I will present a little bit my application. Main activity is map (webview). There are functions which calls different APIs using volley library. After getting response I need to show results on map activity. Until now I always passed activity and called activity methods after processing data from API. Is it wrong approach? I still dont know how to do it correct way. in activity methods i change lot of variables, views etc..

Comment: @JanPetrskovský you can implement a callback interface instead of passing the activity object directly. Once the API call is done, you can simply call the method in the interface to get status of the API call

Comment: I have callback interface, problem is, that my volley requests are in separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for two separate, unrelated classes to have the same method declared, then an [`interface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) is what you're looking for. Take the following example interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void method(AppCompatActivity activity);
}
```

Both of your activities can now `implement` this interface and pass themselves as a parameter as they both `extend AppCompatActivity`. As a result they're forced to define this method e.g.

```
public Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super(savedInstanceState);
         method(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void method(AppCompatActivity activity) {
         // Definition goes here 
    }
}
```

Likewise you can then refer to either of your activities from another class as an instance of `MyInterface`, e.g.

```
// Not an actual way of declaring an Activity but just for demonstration purposes
MyInterface activity1 = new Activity1();
MyInterface activity1 = new Activity2();
```

As both of your classes extend `AppCompatActivity`, [Sagar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50929472/469080) will also work equally well in this instance. However, this solution will work regardless of inheritance path.

---

**EDIT** Apologies, I've only just noticed the [Kotlin] tag, it wasn't immediately clear in the question. The Kotlin equivalent would be:

```
public Activity1 : AppCompatActivity(), MyInterface {
    override fun onResume(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
         super(savedInstanceState);
         method(this);
    }

    override fun method(activity: AppCompatActivity) {
         // Definition goes here 
    }
}
```